# Setting the layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to set the layout in a android app so that a edit text takes most of the screen and a button is at bottom. How do I do that dynamically?

[image: screenshot]

Though I want the text field to be balanced out with all remaining space.

Thanks in advance.

This question has been answered and I got the solution. Then why in world it is being flagged as "not constructive"?

This sets an example how to give weight in android xml definitions. No offence but I feel those who voted down this post as vampires who are roaming around to suck blood out of people by getting any kind of excuse even if it's miniscule.

If there are people in community who support open communication, please come here and see how good collection of knowledge is being destroyed by trolls.

In the end I hope I had been clear in last three paragraphs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

very easy

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top|left" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: First, I want to do it dynamically. Second it didn't worked when I tried to set it dynamically. http://snipt.org/vWaj4

Comment: How do I set the weight to fill space dynamically? It can be done in xml no doubt but how do I do it dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

Edit:

```
RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);

layout.setScrollContainer(true);    // Remove this if you would not like the soft keyboard to resize the view
LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

EditText text = new EditText(this);
text.setGravity(Gravity.TOP | Gravity.LEFT);

Button button = new Button(this);
button.setId(1000);     // The ID can be anything really

LayoutParams textParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
textParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ABOVE, button.getId());

LayoutParams buttonParams = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, 100);    // I used a basic height of 100px here
buttonParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM);

text.setLayoutParams(textParams);
button.setLayoutParams(buttonParams);

layout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

layout.addView(text);
layout.addView(button);

setContentView(layout);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <EditText 
        android:id="@+id/edittext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:hint="Enter note here"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Done"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```